# dbWriteTable ignores UTF-8 encoding

Tags: mysql, r, encoding, utf-8, rmysql

I am trying to write my dataframe into mysql table using UTF-8 encoding. The encoding seems to not working properly. When I open the table in a Workbench environment the UTF-8 encoding is not set as it should. Strange characters appears.

[image: Here is the workbench view]

mysql connection:

```
conn = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='pw', dbname='dbname', host='127.0.0.1')
```

setting UTF-8:

```
dbSendQuery(conn, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

the dataframe need to be inserted into mysql table:

```
id = c(1, 2, 3); vnt = c("Individualioji įmonė", "Akcinė Bendrovė", "Mažoji bendrija")
df = data.frame(id, vnt)
```

Writing df to mysql table

```
dbWriteTable(conn,  value = df, name = "mysql_df", row.names=F, append = TRUE)
```

**My question, is it possible to set charset to UTF-8 using dbWriteTable function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The solution is so simple. Right before writing data to mysql you need to overwrite dbConnect object:

```
conn = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='', password='', dbname='', host='127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "Mojibake".  Example: `ž` turned into `Å¾` because `latin1` was involved somewhere.  You have not provided enough info for me to point specifically at what to fix, but [*this Question and Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) should help.  (Search for Mojibake.)

Comment: The desired result would be a vector of vnt = c("Individualioji įmonė", "Akcinė Bendrovė", "Mažoji bendrija") with latin letters. I have no problem with encoding in R, but when i send it to mysql it fails to pick a correct encoding.